# For Each/Next Loop does not walk through all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have created follwoing code. The macro should simply multiply the cells A2:G3000 by 1 so that the format changes from a text to a number. The macro I wrote does so, but only for the active worksheet.. I used the For Each/Next loop as I learned it.

Could somebody help me find my mistake in the code?

```
Sub Format_Change()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets
    Range("M2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*1"
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:W2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("M2:W2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:W3000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("M2:W3000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("M2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
Next sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below, as @Vityata noted, there's realy no need to use so many `Select` and `Selection`, it slows the code down a lot.

Try the code version below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Format_Change()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets
    With sht
        .Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*1"
        .Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("M2:W2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        .Range("M2:W2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("M2:W3000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        .Range("M2:W3000").Copy
        .Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range(.Range("M2"), .Range("M2").CurrentRegion).ClearContents
    End With
Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: +1, but what if the OP wanted to see actually the pages changing and the job being done? It gives a nice feeling somehow to have an Excel file "working" ... Without the `select` you do not see the `action` :)

Comment: @Vityata Yeah you are sitting in front of your front-loading washer and microwave just watching them to finish?

Comment: Different people, different hobbies - https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BdjaJgQU85g/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: @Vityata that's what we need here, some sense of Humor

Comment: @ShaiRado actually Im just recording the makros, thats why I got so many "seletct or selection". Your code works as I imagined mine to work, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In general the code is not good, because it uses too much select and etc. Read here [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). However, if you want to make it a running one, just add `sht.Select` after the for-each loop.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Format_Change()

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        sht.Select
        Range("M2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*1"
        Range("M2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:W2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M2:W2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:W3000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("M2:W3000").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("M2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.ClearContents
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: No, No, No, come on, you're better than that ;)

Comment: OK, +1, but my OCD didn't let me not give an answer without using the `Select`, hope you forgive me ;)

Comment: @Vityata Thanks for the suggestion, I´ll read through. Since I am yet only recording macros that could really help me a lot, thank you for that one!